# How to create an audio file metadata header if I am streaming data to icecast?

Tags: ios, streaming, audio-streaming, aac, icecast

How do I send the metadata header to the icecast server ? I am recording in AAC and streaming it to the icecast server through ios but the file shows corrupt . I suspect that the metadata needs to be added to be able to play a file. How do i send the metadata ? SHould i send it as a string ? What should be the format ?

Comment: please explain it properly..

Comment: I using the exact code in the following post but using aac format.  But unable to play the mp3 on the server. Do i need to send the metadata with the header mentioned in the post ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762019/ice-cast-source-client-for-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata is not required for a stream to function.  If your data is corrupt, you are either encoding it wrong or are sending the wrong `Content-Type` header.

That being said, once you get your stream working, if you would like to send metadata, this is done out-of-band of the actual audio stream.  Metadata is updated with a simple HTTP request to the Icecast server.

```
http://icecast.example.com/admin/metadata?pass=hackme&mode=updinfo&mount=/mountpoint&song=Your%20Metadata
```

You can find more info in my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985297/362536