# Setup Mount Point in icecast server

Tags: ios, ipad, core-audio, icecast

I am developing an app which requires to stream live audio from iOS device to an icecast server and simultaneously play that audio in other iOS devices who are listening to that recorded audio stream.

The problems are:

- How to setup mount point?
- How to record live audio from device to Icecast stream?

Here is my icecast.xml config file:

```
<icecast>
    <!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
         on the server info page of the icecast web interface
         (server_version.xsl). -->
    <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>admin@localhost</admin>

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <threadpool>5</threadpool>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>hackme</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
    <!--
    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
    </directory>
     -->

    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
    It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
    listings. -->
    <hostname>testserver</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8001</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->

    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8001</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->

    <!-- Only define a <mount> section if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
    <mount>
        <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>

        <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <no-yp>1</no-yp>
        <authentication type="htpasswd">
                <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
                <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
        </authentication>
        <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
        <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
    </mount>

    <mount>
        <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
        <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
        </authentication>
    </mount>

    -->

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
                <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/var/log/icecast</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast/admin</adminroot>
        <!-- <pidfile>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.3.3/share/icecast/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
          -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
          -->
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <!-- <chroot>0</chroot> -->
        <!--
        <changeowner>
            <user>nobody</user>
            <group>nogroup</group>
        </changeowner>
        -->
    </security>
</icecast>
```

I have correctly installed icecast server.

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/
```

**I have gone through this post, but of no help:-**

[How to create an audio file metadata header if I am streaming data to icecast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832833/how-to-create-an-audio-file-metadata-header-if-i-am-streaming-data-to-icecast?lq=1)

[Ice cast source client for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762019/ice-cast-source-client-for-ios)

Comment: Hi, Have you done this? Could you please help me on the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check if your mount point has been configured properly. Use this player to broadcast to your mount point - [Link](http://kb.voscast.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=3&id=18&artlang=en)

Use VLC to listen to the mount point. [Link](https://www.bauer-martin.com/server/icecast-mit-vlc-als-streaming-client-312.html) mentions

Once you configure the mountpoint you should be able to listen to the stream with VLC player that you are broadcasting via the butt player. Let me know once you configure the mount point.

Comment: How to configure mountpoint in  icecast.xml file? What exactly to write there for mounpoint section that butt could connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Icecast server IP:Port listed are local; have you tested external to make sure you stream is accessible externally?

This is what you need to verify before testing anything else, making sure you Icecast2 server can resolve external requests on that port. Please make sure you edit your router's firewall with the ports you want to use e.g. 8001, 8002, etc.

"http://externalIP:port/mountpount" this is how you test external access in web browser

[image: image of external access to Icecast server]

You can check out my Icecast streams at http://www.audiofraternity.uk and you'll see multiple streams (individual mount points for each DJ) I'm assuming this is what your trying to achieve but using IOS app for each DJ.

[image: image of multiple djs mounts on a website with player for each DJ]